# Why would you need a DispatchQueue when showing Alerts on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift, and trying to examine a finished project. But there is something i couldn't understand.

After a network request is completed, the app show an alert under a condition.

```
func makeNetworkRequest() {
   //newtork result...
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.showAlert(versionMessage: "Error")
   }
} 

func showAlert(versionMessage: String) {
   let alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: versionMessage, delegate: self)
   alert.show()
}
```

However, it is done with a `DispatchQueue`. Why would anyone need to use `DispatchQueue` in this situation.

Comment: UI code must always be done on the main queue.

Comment: and network is (usually) made outside main thread. Dispatch tells that the code inside must goes back to the main thread

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-must-the-UI-always-be-updated-on-Main-Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It’s a conscious design decision from Apple’s side to not have `UIKit`
>   be thread-safe. Making it thread-safe wouldn’t buy you much in terms
>   of performance; it would in fact make many things slower. And the fact
>   that `UIKit` is tied to the main thread makes it very easy to write
>   concurrent programs and use `UIKit`. All you have to do is make sure
>   that calls into `UIKit` are always made on the main thread. So
>   according to this the fact that `UIKit` objects must be accessed on
>   the main thread is a design decision by apple to favor performance.

for more detailed information you can go through this article

https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/thread-safe-class-design/

In your case , You are showing alert from  another thread so you have to write code under the MainThread so , you can get the main thread using below code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
       // Your UI Updation here 
   }
```

**Reason**

In Cocoa Touch, the `UIApplication` i.e. the instance of your application is attached to the main thread because this thread is created by `UIApplicatioMain()`, the entry point function of Cocoa Touch. It sets up main event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing events. Application's main event loop receives all the UI events i.e. touch, gestures etc.

Answer (score 1):

You´ll for sure notice that the alert will lag if you don´t show the alert on the main thread, that´s because your UI code does always have to be done on your main thread.

So if you're on a background thread and want to execute code on the main thread, you need to call `async()`. That´s way you call `DispatchQueue.main`, which is the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However i couldn't see any difference, when commenting the DispatchQueue.main part.

Comment: Sometimes it does @hackio, if it does and you don´t run it on the main thread update it and you´ll see the difference.